# Git/Gitlab: Is there a built-in way to enforce custom requirements before merging?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'd like to prevent any branch that meets certain conditions from being merged into "master", e.g. if the branch would add the string "//BLOCKER", the merge must abort.

I've accomplished this on my own machine with a bash alias, but is there any built-in way in gitlab (or even git itself) to enforce it on a project wide level?

The only approach I could think of was to make the CI pipeline fail on such a condition, but this would make pre-merge testing harder.

Comment: On the server side, deploy a `pre-receive` hook. The hook checks the contents of a new push and declines it if it doesn't pass the test. The host services like Gitlab may have a similar hook with different names.

Comment: So, [git server-side hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#_an_example_git_enforced_policy) are the feature I was looking for. Thanks a lot! This solves the question for me. Make it an answer if you like :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html

> Git natively supports hooks that are executed on different actions.
>   Examples of server-side git hooks include pre-receive, post-receive,
>   and update. See [Git SCM Server-Side Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks) for more information
>   about each hook type.